# Creating a array of binary numbers in Processing 3 issue

Tags: arrays, binary, processing

I can't figure out why my code doesn't work...

```java
int n = 1023;

int[] a = new int[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a[i] = binary(i,10);             //problem line
}
```

I keep getting an error saying "cannot convert from String to int" but i can't see where the string is coming from. I'm just trying to make an array where each element is itself in binary.

```java
[0] = 000000000
[1] = 000000001
[2] = 000000010
[3] = 000000011
[4] = 000000100
etc...
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What variable is binary?

Comment: @Hazza You could use bit shifting (```for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    a[i] = 1 << i;}```) to get powers of two. Bare in mind 2 to the power of 1023 is a pretty large value (beyond what int or long can store)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`binary()`](https://processing.org/reference/binary_.html) function returns a `String` value. From the reference:

> Converts an int, byte, char, or color to a String containing the equivalent binary notation. For example, the color value produced by color(0, 102, 153, 255) will convert to the String value "11111111000000000110011010011001".

It doesn't really make sense to say that you want an array of binary numbers. Numbers are just numbers. Whether they're in binary or hexadecimal or decimal only matters when you want to **display** those numbers, which is why the `binary()` function returns a `String` value.

You either need to store your values as `String` values representing the binary notation (and then use the `unbinary()` function to convert them to an `int` when you need to), or you need to store them as regular `int` values and only use the `binary()` function when you need to display them.